# Storage Access Framework - Some methods of DocumentsContract not compiled when included in my Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, storage-access-framework

I would like to add Storage Access Framework support to my app.

I created an utility Java class for some SAF operations.

I added it to a sample project with

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
minSdkVersion 25
targetSdkVersion 29
```

and

```
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;
```

is inclued.

It is successfully compiled.

My app has

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 26
```

But I see that the method names in

```
DocumentContracts.copyDocument()
```

and

```
DocumentContracts.removeDocument()
```

are in red (but they belong to API level 19).

If I include

```
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;
```

I see that

```
documentfile
```

is in red.

Note that auto-completion works on

```
DocumentsContract
```

and shows me many methods from SAF.

Furthermore I see that some exceptions are not required anymore like when

```
renameDocument()
```

or

```
createDocument()
```

are used.

What is wrong? What is the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your app has `minSdkVersion 21` (= the app promises to run on android-21 and newer) while your lib has `minSdkVersion 25` (=the lib tells that it can not run on android-24 or older)

so your 21-app cannot use your 25-lib

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is good:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
minSdkVersion 25
targetSdkVersion 29
```

and

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```